# APIs that allow status updates to be posted to several sites?

Tags: java, ruby, facebook, twitter

Does anyone know of an API that will allow for posting status updates to Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tried it but [Messagepub](http://messagepub.com/) sounds like what you need.

[image]
<sub>(source: [messagepub.com](http://messagepub.com/images/diagram.png))</sub>

Comment: -1 does not exist anymore (sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Google search:

java twitter api -> http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/

java facebook api -> http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

java linkedin api -> http://www.slideshare.net/linkedin/linkedins-communication-architecture <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>Not really an API link but the video presentation might help

Comment: Is there one that combines all of these?